# Total Newbie. Cannot log into my first test app using grant_type=password

Tags: api, oauth2, authentication

I have set up a test application on my developer instance of Salesforce. I have a client_id, client_secret and I have the necessary security token appended to my password.

I am trying to authenticate using the password grant type. When I send the following http request (using Postman) to

```
https://na16.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: na6.salesforce.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&client_id=XXXXX&client_secret=YYYYY&username=my.name%40mydomain.com&password=PWDSECURITYTOKEN
```

I receive the following JSON result:

```
{
    "error_description": "authentication failure",
    "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

Any idea what I can look at to debug this? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their help. I actually did get this to work, but unfortunately, I had compensating errors, so there really wasn't one cause. In the end, all the parameters were correct, but the URL I was using was incorrect. I think my major mistake was not using URL form encoded at first.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to make sure that the user you are logging in with has access to the connected app that you created, and that the connected app includes the "access to data via the web" scope enabled.
Also, make sure you put the elements in the form section of Postman, and not in the Header. For the authentication flow, you shouldn't need any headers.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Still no luck. Postman says it's sending a form and the body has the parameters (see above), so I think that's in order. I did edit the test app and changed permitted users to all users may self-authorize and set the IP Relaxation to Relax IP restrictions. I do not have a start web url or start mobile url. Is that bad?

Comment: Don't use the self authorize option, that assumes there will be a UI interaction for the user to "accept" the authorization request. Set it to "pre-authorized by Admin" (whatever that option is called), and make sure the profile of your test user has the Connected App listed in their profile.

Comment: Thank you again. As I said, total newbie :-). I am not using a test user. I am trying to authenticate me (using the username and password I use to get into the developer site instance) and I am the administrator of the site (I assume, since I created it) so I think I would have access and privilege to the app. Do I need to include any specific profiles?

Comment: You need 5o edit the system administrator profile, and add your connected app to the connected apps assigned to the profile.

Comment: In 'Connected App Detail', I have assigned several profiles to my app. System Administrator is one of the profiles I assigned to the app. Is this correct? Is there some other place I need to make this link? I tried editing the administrator profile and did not see a way of associating my app with that profile. Once again, thank you for the assistance.

Comment: I looked more closely at the System Administrator Profile and my app is listed under 'Connected App Access' and the 'API Enabled' option is checked. I'm beginning to lose hope. :-(

Comment: Check your login history and see if you are hitting the login at all.  If you are, it might be a password or security token issue. If you don't see it, it might be an issue if the connected app configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can read below document for correct oauth links

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_oauth_endpoints.htm

If you are using Prod your oauth end point will be as below

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

If you are on the Sandbox ,your oauth end point will be as below

https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Hope correcting end points resolves your issues

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately, changing the URL did not solve the problem.